# How to deploy React-Native app to my iPhone using Xcode 13.3?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, react-native

After upgrading my Xcode to 13.3 I've noticed a change that doesn't allow my react-native app to be added in my phone using the **release mode** option from **"Edit Schema"** anymore. I can add it to my iPhone just fine and be able to use it, but after I disconnect from the same wifi it doesn't work anymore. Basically, the way it used to work is by following the next steps:

Go to Xcode

**1)** Click on Product

**2)** Click on Scheme

**3)** Click on Edit Schema

**4)** Finally choose **release** option instead of Debug option, then run it and that was it.

This way I didn't have to be connected to the same wifi all the time, and simply go to anywhere that I wanted and be able to use my app just fine.

I want to do the same but I see a **different screen now:** when I go to "Edit Schema"

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can release my app and not having to be connected to the same wifi all the time? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I guess you just need to select the "run" tab to select your schema.

Comment: Otherwise you can run your app from terminal to your device with `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release --device "Your Device Name"`

Comment: Or just `npm run ios --configuration Release --device`

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** Suggested by @Thibault, this worked for me. Thanks!

```
react-native run-ios --scheme "Your Device Name"
```